# How to combine a slice and array into map

Tags: go

I'm trying to create a morse code map in Go. How do I do this? I can also convert one slice into an array if that makes it any easier.

```golang
   alphabet := []string{}
    for i := 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++ {
        alphabet = append(alphabet, string(i))
    }
    fmt.Println(alphabet)
    
    morseSlice := [26]string{".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."}
    
    // convert to map that maps letters to morse
    var morseDict map[string]string
    
    for i := 0; i > len(morseSlice); i++ {
        morseDict[alphabet[i]] = morseSlice[i]
    }
    
    fmt.Println(morseDict)
```

but my map is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the condition in for loop is wrong, `i > len(morseSlice)` must be `i < len(morseSlice)`

Comment: `morseSlice := [26]string` my gosh, that's confusing... an array called `slice`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will throw an error `assignment to entry in nil map`. To resolve that, you need to initialise it.

```
elementMap := make(map[string]string) //Initialize
```

And your condition should be changed to `less than` or you can use `range`

```
for i, ele := range alphabet {
  elementMap[ele] = morseSlice[i]
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-iLNXoJcd3y)

Comment: Just `elementMap := make(map[string]string)` should be enough. The `var` and double type declaration isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks Shadab. I get confused often with this simple powerful concept.

Comment: What did I do if not initialize  the map? Did I not? What did I do then?

Comment: You declared it but didn't allocate, initialze.